# Pandas Datetime conversion

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have the following dataframe;

```
Date = ['01-Jan','01-Jan','01-Jan','01-Jan']                                                    
Heure = ['00:00','01:00','02:00','03:00']
value =[1,2,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':value,'Date':Date,'Hour':Heure})  
print(df)

     Date   Hour  value
0  01-Jan  00:00      1
1  01-Jan  01:00      2
2  01-Jan  02:00      3
3  01-Jan  03:00      4
```

I am trying to create a datetime index, knowing that the file I am working with is for 2015. I have tried a lot of things but can get it to work! I tried to only convert the date and the month, but even that does not work:

```
df.index  = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%d-%m')
```

I expect the following result:

```
                      Date   Hour     value
2015-01-01 00:00:00  01-Jan  00:00      1
2015-01-01 01:00:00  01-Jan  01:00      2
2015-01-01 02:00:00  01-Jan  02:00      3
2015-01-01 03:00:00  01-Jan  03:00      4
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitely add `2015` somehow, and include the `Hour` column as well. I would do something like this:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.Date + '-2015 ' + df.Hour, format='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M')

>>> df
                       Date   Hour  value
2015-01-01 00:00:00  01-Jan  00:00      1
2015-01-01 01:00:00  01-Jan  01:00      2
2015-01-01 02:00:00  01-Jan  02:00      3
2015-01-01 03:00:00  01-Jan  03:00      4
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that works perfectly! so month is %b then

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). `%b` is *Month as locale’s abbreviated name.*

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the default 1900 by using `replace`

```
s=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+df['Hour'],format='%d-%b%H:%M').apply(lambda x : x.replace(year=2015))
s
Out[131]: 
0   2015-01-01 00:00:00
1   2015-01-01 01:00:00
2   2015-01-01 02:00:00
3   2015-01-01 03:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]

df.index=s
```